# get id of selected spinner data based from database android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

hi i have this spinner dropdown that displays data from my database. In my database, i have this table named `area` and it has this fields, `aid` its primary key and `location` which is a varchar. so far i am successful in displaying the data im my spinner. in my DBHelper this is the code that gets the data from DB

```
public Set<String> getAllData()
{
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_AREA;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            set.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return set;
}
```

then in my addLocation.java here is how i use it to display the data on my spinner

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addplace);
    Spinner spn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.areas);

    Set<String> aset = db.getAllData();
    List<String> aData = new ArrayList<>(aset);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            aData);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spn.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerInfo());
}

private class SpinnerInfo implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private boolean isFirst = true;
    String selected;
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View selectedView, int selectedIndex, long id)
    {
        if (isFirst)
        {
            isFirst = false;
        }
        else
        {
            String selection = spinner.getItemAtPosition(selectedIndex).toString();
            selected = selection;
        }
        Toast tempMessage =
                Toast.makeText(addLocation.this,
                        selected,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        tempMessage.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner) {
    // Won’t be invoked unless you programmatically remove entries
    }
}
```

the thing is i needed to get the id of the selected location not the index in the spinner but it's database id. any idea on how i can do this? thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why using `Set ` for String locations?

Comment: just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and you will have your `id ` as the last parameter of `onItemSelected` method

Comment: hi @pskink how do i use the SimpleCursorAdapter? thanks!

Comment: just get the `Cursor` with your data and pass it to `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor, that's all

Answer (score -1):

> i needed to get the id of the selected location not the index in the
>   spinner but it's database id. any idea on how i can do this?

Do it as using HashMap:

**1.** Use HashMap instead of `Set` with location as a key and location id as value. change `getAllData()` :

```
public Map<String, Integer> getAllData()
{
    Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
     ...
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            hashMap.put(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return hashMap;
}
```

**2.** Pass all keys to Spinner :

```
  Map<String, Integer> hashMap = db.getAllData();
  List<String> allLocations = new ArrayList<String>(hashMap.keySet());
```

**3.** Now In `onItemSelected`  use `selected` String to get id of Selected item:

```
int location_id=hashMap.get(selected);
```

Comment: hi the return hashMap is returning this error `Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>', required: 'java.util.Set<java.lang.String>'`

Comment: in my `onItemSelected` do i need to declare a new Map? because i hade error on the `int location_id=hashMap.get(selected);` part

Comment: in my `onItemSelected` it says that `Cannot Resolve Symbol 'hashMap'`

Comment: @BourneShady: then declare `Map<String, Integer> hashMap` object outside method and use `hashMap = db.getAllData();` instead of ` Map<String, Integer> hashMap = db.getAllData();`

Comment: here is what my onItemSelected looks like. am i doing it right `public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View selectedView, int selectedIndex, long id)
        {
            if (isFirst)
            {
                isFirst = false;
            }
            else
            {
                int location_id=hashMap.get(selected);
            }

        }`